# Scanned PDFs and searching?

Tags: search, pdf

We are using SharePoint 2013. Our administrator is trying to come up with a solution to make scanned PDFs searchable. Can anyone recommend a remedy for this issue?

Comment: pdf search is totally supported on SharePoint 2013, your problem comes if you want to search into the document, this will not work because it are scanned not on OCR, the documents will be simple images and you will not be abble to crewled or search

Answer (score 2):

What you need is good OCR software.  I've had pretty good luck with [KnowledgeLake](https://www.knowledgelake.com/intelligent-content-delivery-sharepoint) but there are plenty of other options.

[SharePoint Scan and OCR App](https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104295830&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false) - seems to be able to take documents already in SharePoint and convert them.

[Aquaforest Searchlight](https://www.aquaforest.com/en/searchlight.asp)

[ABBYY](https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/solutions/sharepoint/features/)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your scanning the documents to OCR (Optical character recognition), it can be crawled and indexed by the Search Service Application. You can easily test this by trying to select text of your scanned PDF. If you can select text, copy it, and paste it to notepad - you're good to go.

See more: [Configuring SharePoint for PDF Files](https://www.aquaforest.com/wp/index.php/configuring-sharepoint-for-pdf-files/)